# UnicodeDecodeError: ('unknown', u'\xe0', 0, 1, '')

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
temp = "à la Carte"
print type(temp)
utemp = unicode(temp)
```

The code above results in an error.
My goal is to process the temp string and use a find to check if it contains specific string in it but cannot process due to the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: ('unknown', u'\xe0', 0, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the encoding: otherwise `unicode()` doesn't know what `\xe0` means, because that is encoding-specific.

```
>>> temp = "à la Carte"
>>> utemp = unicode(temp,encoding="Windows-1252")
>>> utemp
u'\xe0 la Carte'
>>> print utemp
à la Carte
```

Answer (score 1):

In python 2, the ordinary string literal cannot hold such unicode characters, so even if the parser manages to get through it, it is still an error. That's why there exists a unicode literal type. So to make it work, first you have to declare the encoding of the python file, and second, use a unicode literal. Like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
temp = u"à la Carte"
print type(temp)
utemp = unicode(temp)
```